# Nested For loops to print numbers 11223344556677889900

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to print the sequence of numbers `11223344556677889900` using nested for loops.  I am unsure of the algorithm to print the sequence since it ends in `00`.  I have the following method code but I print the `00` as literals and am sure that there must be a better way.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
public static void drawNumbers(){
    for (int line = 1; line <= 2; line++) {
        for (int i =1; i <= 9; i++) {
            for (int j =1; j<=2; j++) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
        }   
        System.out.print("00");
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic seems fine for me. You could also print until `10` and check if the input is `10` then print `0` instead.

Comment: what is the usage of printing these numbers, seriously?

Comment: You could also go from 11 to 100 but only print the last two digits ... `(j % 100)`

Comment: Please look at the answers and accept the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your loop up to 10 and instead of:

```
System.out.print(i);
```

do:

```
System.out.print(i % 10);
```

---

```
public static void drawNumbers(){
    for (int line = 1; line <= 2; line++){
        for (int i =1; i <= 10; i++){
            for (int j =1; j<=2; j++){
                System.out.print(i%10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the "i" loop until 10 and print i%10. This would print 0 when the value reaches 10.

Answer (score 0):

One other way would be to insert an if statement inside the for where you would check if the value of i was equal to "10", and if it were, it would print the value "00"

Answer (score 0):

Changed the logic a little to fit your requirement

```
public static void drawNumbers() {
    for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
        for (int i =1; i <= 10; i++) {
            for (int j =1; j<=2; j++) {
                if(i==10) {
                    System.out.print(0);        
                } else {
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

To use only one loop run it like

```
public static void drawNumbers() {
    for(int i = 1 ;i <= 10; i++) {
        if(i ==10) {
            System.out.print(0 + "" + 0);   
        } else {
            System.out.print(i + "" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just only print the last digit of `i`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    String s = String.valueOf(i);
    int lastDigit = s.length() - 1; // last digit position in string
    System.out.print(s.substring(lastDigit, lastDigit + 1)); // print last digit
    System.out.print(s.substring(lastDigit, lastDigit + 1)); // print last digit
}
```

Output:

```
11223344556677889900
```